# subspace topology and krull conincide in galois group are coincide proof

Tags: galois-theory

Theorem:

If $L/K$ is Galois and $E$ is an intermediate field, then the subspace topology on $\text{Gal}(L/E)$ as a subset of $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ equals the Krull topology on $\text{Gal}(L/E)$.
I want to prove that the open set of $\text{Gal}(L/E)$ under krull topology is also open set of subspace topology of $\text{Gal}(L/K)$

So the following is online proof:
Now let $V$ be an open subset of $\text{Gal}(L/E)$ for its Krull topology. To show $V$ is also open for the subspace topology that $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ gives $\text{Gal}(L/E)$, we may assume $V \neq \emptyset$. Pick $\sigma \in V$, so $\sigma \text{Gal}(L/F) \subset V$ for some finite extension $F/E$.Write F = E(α) and set $F'= K(α)$. Then

- $F'/K$ is a finite extension( this is the problem I don't have any idea)

and $σ Gal(L/F')$ = {$τ ∈ Gal(L/E) : τ |F' = σ|F'$} = {$τ ∈ Gal(L/E) : τ (α) = σ(α)$}.This set is {$τ ∈ Gal(L/K) : τ (α) = σ(α)$}$∩Gal(L/E) =σGal(L/K(α))∩Gal(L/E)$, which is an open subset of $Gal(L/E)$ for its subspace topology in $Gal(L/K)$. Thus $V$ is open for the subspace topology of $Gal(L/E)$ being inside $Gal(L/K)$

Can someone help me understant this question?
Thanks